# Unable to install Linux header for current kernel with pacman

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I have installed kernel version 3.16.1-1 but i am unable to install the linux headers, as pacman attempts to install the latest version. How do i install the right kernel headers? I am using a UDOO Quad.

```
# uname -r
3.16.1-1-ARCH

# pacman -S linux-armv7-headers
resolving dependencies...
looking for inter-conflicts...
:: linux-armv7-headers and linux-am33x-headers are in conflict (linux-headers). Remove linux-am33x-headers? [y/N] y

Packages (2): linux-am33x-headers-4.1.3-3 [removal]  linux-armv7-headers-4.1.4-1

Total Download Size:    6.26 MiB
Total Installed Size:   43.26 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:       1.59 MiB

# pacman -S linux-armv7-headers-3.16.1-1
error: target not found: linux-armv7-headers-3.16.1-1
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to specify the version when you try to install:

```
pacman -S linux-armv7-headers-3.16.1-1
```

Comment: As you can see i have already tried that, and it failed.

Comment: Maybe it's not in the package database. Did you try to search: `pacman -Ss linux-.*-headers`?

Answer (score 1):

Update the database.

```
$ sudo pacman -Syy
```

Then update your linux

```
$ sudo pacman -S linux
```

Reboot so new kernel loads. Then install linux-header.

```
$ sudo pacman -S linux-headers
```

Or whichever kernel you want.

**NOTE:** See comments below. This can break your system.

Comment: Be careful with this. After running those first 2 commands and rebooting, I am unable to get back to the login screen. Likely just a quirk of the distro that I'm using (Antergos w/ Cinnamon), but I expect that other arch noobs like myself will find this answer and try it.

Comment: @eric `pacman -Syy` can break the system. Did you check if gdm started using Wayland instead of x11? See here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM (at bottom)

Comment: It was in a virtual machine, so I already rolled back to an earlier snapshot. When I get some time later, I'll see if I can reproduce it for the sake of learning and helping others :)